# Android datepicker error

Tags: android, android-datepicker

Why showdialog() in the following code shows "The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated"?

```
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID); 
                Date d=new Date();
                //d.getMinutes();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+d, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Because showDialog(int id) method is deprecated. So you have to use DialogFragment.

Answer (score 1):

Because `showDialog(int id)` method is deprecated. Try to implement `DialogFragment` [Default android date picker](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker).

Answer (score 0):

As you've said, the method has been deprecated. Fragment based dialogs are preferred now. Please see the [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
final Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            }
        }, date.get(Calendar.YEAR), date.get(Calendar.MONTH), date.get(Calendar.DATE));

dateDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

`showdialog()` method  is deprecated.Try to follow [this](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/10/creating-datepicker-using.html) tutorial.